# facebook like box undocumented error (14040003)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have added multiple facebook like box to a webpage. They are all showing up. When I click on "Like", there's an error showing up :

Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: We're working on this issue and will have it fixed soon. Check the Known Issues on Facebook page for more information.

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/error/coded?code=1404003&message=Sorry%2C+this+feature+isn%27t+available+right+now%3A+We%27re+working+on+this+issue+and+will+have+it+fixed+soon.+Check+the+Known+Issues+on+Facebook+page+for+more+information.&hash=AQDmg_dFTgfVQ5o6

The code is pretty simple :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_ACTUAL_APP_ID&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then a simple loop in Rails :

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="<%= startup.facebook_url %>" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

You can also check the end result here : https://iloveqcstartups.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Just as a side note, if you are not connected to facebook and click on "Like", it prompts you to log in to facebook. It then works very well. As soon as you fresh the page, it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ever gets this problem, the solution was to switch over to a full domain name.

I don't know if the problem was herokuapp.com, or the https.